# Running Hudson job on multiple nodes

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I'm looking a bit into Hudson, and can't seem to find the option to tell it to run a configured job on a few nodes/labels.
How can I configure a job to run on both Linux and Solaris every time there's a new commit? Do I have to duplicate the job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a matrix build.  When creating a new job, this is shown as a "Build multi-configuration project".

When configuring the job there'll be a section called "Configuration Matrix" where you can choose "Build on multiple nodes".